# Selenium 3 InternetExplorerDriver Setup

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver, selenium3

I'm trying to set up a type of boiler-plate code for WebDriver that I can give to anyone in my QA team to help them test. My problem is that I can't seem to get Internet Explorer working. It's throwing errors and I have no idea how to fix them or if its some sort of naming issue. 
The driver files are all in my C:\ Drive.

chromedriver.exe,  geckodriver.exe,  IEDriverServer.exe

Errors in the code below are //commented

```
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.ie.IEDriverService; //The import org.openqa.selenium.ie.IEDriverService cannot be resolved

public class Loginmethod {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\\\geckodriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\\\chromedriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); //InternetExplorerDriver cannot be resolved to a type
    driver.get("http://www.google.com/");

    Thread.sleep(100);


}
}
```

Additionally, If anyone would know a way to test for Safari using windows 10 with selenium, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you are trying to import is not the class you are using.

You are importing `IEDriverService` but using the `InternetExplorerDriver` class.

change your code to import `InternetExplorerDriver`.

Comment: Ahh I see. When I put in the System.setProperty line in for IE, it somehow auto-added IEDriverService in the imports section.

Comment: glad i could help :)

Comment: After changing the code as you said, it still throws the same errors. Except in eclipse they're icon is grayed instead of being bright pink.

Comment: Update: Ran the code a couple times and the errors went away. Working great now!